# How to use fcnchk in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, input, arguments, built-in

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use fcnchk correctly for this implementation:

```
function [w,t,flg] = RKF(FunFcnIn, Intv, alpha, tol, stepsize)
% On input: 
%   FunFcnIn is the name of function to be integrated
%   A call to FunFcnIn with argument (t, y) returns f(t,y).
```

What type of input does FunFcnIn need to be in order to evaluate it as the comment suggests?

Comment: Without any context who knows? Probably an anonymous function or an .m file.

Comment: fcnchk is bulit-in, but I can't find much help with how to use it.

Comment: From "FunFcnIn is the **name** of function to be integrated", I'd look at [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) ... ?  But yeah, more information and context is needed for definiteness.